# Confusion with change of basis and linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, change-of-basis

"Given the basis $B={(1;2),(-1;1)}, B1={(1;5),(-1;1)}$ and the linear transformation $T$ from $R^2 to R^2$ defined by $T(1;5)=(7;5)$ and $T(-1;1)=(3;-3)$ find the matrices $[T]BC$, $[T]B1C$, $[T]CC$ and $[T]BB
 $

C=standard basis

Hi, I'm having a lot of trouble with this excercise. The thing is that I can't identify the basis that I am working with, because the activity says "$T(1;5)=(7;5)$ and $T(-1;1)=(3;-3)$" but how can I know what transformation is it? I mean, is it $[T]CC$? Or $[T]B1C$? Or is it $[T]B1B1$? 
Because both vectors are written in the standar basis, aren't they? So that transformation must be [T]CC.

So, I need some help because I'm very confused. Obviously I don't want you to do it for me, but to explain it well to me, and if you can, do one of them as an example, please.

Comment: Can you specify what is meant by $C$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is used for "standard basis"

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is always the same. Now, in order to compute, say, the matrix $[T]_B^B$, the first thing to do is to compute the images of the vectors of $B$. Since$$(1,2)=\frac12(1,5)+\frac12(-1,1),$$you have $T(1,2)=\frac12(7,5)+\frac12(3,-3)=(5,1)$. And, of course, $T(-1,1)=(3,-3)$. Now you express these vectors in the basis $B$:

- $(5,1)=2(1,2)-3(-1,1)$;
- $(3,-3)=-3(-1,1)$.

So,$$[T]_B^B=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\-3&-3\end{bmatrix}.$$The other matrices can be obtained by the same process.

Comment: But when the excercise tells me what are the transformated vectors of B1, is it telling me that the linear transformation eats B vectors and spits out C vectors? Or what? How can I know it?